# I need javascript/html assistance with making a textfield (not)readOnly

Tags: javascript, html

I find myself at a loss. I am charged with the seemingly trivial task of making a text field (not) read only, if some condition is true. well, I have hit the wall.

I have tried various versions of the following:

```
if(someTextBox.enable==false){
                                    someTextBox.enable=true;}
```

including

```
                                    someTextBox.setAttribute("enable", true);
```

and even

```
someTextBox.setAttribute("readOnly", true);
```

I am using Chrome devtools, and can see various incarnations of null, including ignored if-clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:
`document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = false;`

Comment: I thought I had already tried this; obviously not. Thanks